# Can IP packet with TTL=1 reach loopback interface of a switch?

Tags: ip

This is a question that bothers me a lot. And I cannot argue with colleagues because all switches I see can response the ping request even my TTL=1.

So my question is, does TTL decrease between interfaces on a switch? For example, I have 192.168.1.1/24 on interface 0/1, 192.168.2.1/24 on interface 0/2 and a loopback interface with 1.1.1.1/32. If I connect my PC on interface 0/1, should I be able to ping interface 0/2 and loopback interface on the switch?

Edit: The switch I mentioned above is actually a router. Sorry for a confusing question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a TTL value of 1 is sufficient.

According to [RFC791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#page-30) for IPv4 and [RFC2460](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460#page-5) for IPv6, the TTL value is a decremented by 1 whenever the packet is forwarded by a node. Since the packet is not forwarded when it is passed on to the loopback interface, the TTL is not decremented and a TTL of 1 is sufficient. The IP datagram does not egress on an interface and therefore is not forwarded to another node.

Comment: The loopback _is_ an interface, and the IPv4 TTL is supposed to be decremented by the IP module, by at least 1, before it is forwarded to the loopback. The loopback is on a different network, so the packet is actually routed from the VLAN network to the loopback network.

Comment: RFC791 does not say that TTL is decremented when a routing decision is made, only when the IP header is processed, which is a bit vague.  All the major vendors (Cisco, HPE, Juniper) do not decrement TTL for local interfaces.

Comment: @Ron Maupin♦ Yes, the loopback interface is a network interface. But it is not a another hop and the datagram does not leave the current hop.

Comment: @user2964971, yes, it is another hop, and the TTL is decremented, and it drops a packet. Just try it on a Cisco router. Look at the edit to my answer.

Comment: @Karl Billington The same RFC literally specifies a time to live. On [page](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc791#page-14) 14: _The maximum time the datagram is allowed to remain in the internet system._. On [page](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc791#page-30) 30: _The time is measured in units of seconds_.

Comment: @Ron Maupin♦ : OP's question is about network theory. That's way I was talking about RFCs.

Comment: I suppose our comments are a good example what might have driven the author's of [RFC2460](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2460#page-5) to explicitly state: _...decremented by 1 by each node that forwards the packet_.

Comment: @user2964971, yes, and according to the RFC, when the IP module processes the packet, it must decrement it by at least 1. That is what happens in routers, even when forwarding to an interface in the same router where the packet was received. It is unfortunate, that none of the PC OS manufacturers actually follow the RFC, but the router OSes do. The IPv6 RFC makes it clear that the IPv4 TTL is supposed to work that way, but that the OSes don't do that, so IPv6 adopted a Hop Limit instead of the TTL.

Comment: You are right. Here is the passage from [RFC791](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc791#page-30): _This field must be decreased at each point that the internet header is processed to reflect the time spent processing the datagram._

Comment: It would beven more clear if the IPv4 RFC gave something like the IPv6 RFC does: `if the IPv6 Hop Limit is less than or equal to 1 {
           send an ICMP Time Exceeded -- Hop Limit Exceeded in
           Transit message to the Source Address and discard the
           packet
        }
        else {
           decrement the Hop Limit by 1

           resubmit the packet to the IPv6 module for transmission
           to the new destination
        }`

Comment: The key is that if the Hop Limit is less than _or equal to_ 1, then discard the packet.

Comment: That was true until last summer: RFC2460 is obsolete. [RFC8200](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8200#page-7): _A node that is the destination of a packet should not discard a packet with Hop Limit equal to zero_. However in RFC speak, _should_ is not mandatory.

Comment: That is the same for RFC 2460, which changed the IPv4 to TTL because of the IPv4 behavior of the PC OSes. RFC 2460 specifically says that the Hop Limit is for nodes that _forward_ the packet: "_Decremented by 1 by each node that forwards the packet. The packet is discarded if Hop Limit is decremented to zero_," and "_That is the reason the IPv4 'Time to Live' field was renamed 'Hop Limit' in IPv6._"

Comment: @user2964971 I wasn’t disagreeing with you, I am an the side that local interfaces don’t decrement TTL

Comment: I think I agree with @user2964971, at least in IPv6, as RFC says the router should process the packet regardless of hop limit once the it received the packet.

Answer (score 3):

Layer-3 devices (routers, PCs, etc.) are supposed to decrease the TTL on IPv4 packets as the network stack processes the packet (see [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/43508/8499) for a full explanation). Most PC OSes do not actually do this, but routers do. The IPv4 TTL is really supposed to reflect the processing time.

On the other hand, layer-2 switches are transparent devices that only look at the frame, which encapsulates the packet. The switches do not know or care about anything in the packet. This lets them carry any type of layer-3 protocol (IPv4, IPX, IPv6, AppleTalk, etc.), even at the same time. You would not, for example, want to replace all your switches when adding or changing to IPv6, which has a different IP header than IPv4.

Your example of a loopback is like a host on a different network, and your packet must be routed to a different network, so the TTL will be decremented. When it reaches `0`, the packet will be discarded. Basically, any packet with a TTL of `1` reaching a router will be dropped, unless the packet is for the router interface where it entered the router.

On the other hand, if the switch is using an SVI, the SVI will be on the the same LAN as the source, and the frame is switched at layer-2, so the TTL is never decremented.

---

**Edit:**

Here is an example where I pinged the next-hop router VLAN interface, and then I pinged the router Loopback0 interface, with a TTL of 1. I received ICMP replies for every ping attempt, but the pings to the loopback expired in transit:

```
D:\>ping 198.18.1.1

Pinging 198.18.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 198.18.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 198.18.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 198.18.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 198.18.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 198.18.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

D:\>ping -i 1 198.0.0.8

Pinging 198.0.0.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 198.18.1.1: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 198.18.1.1: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 198.18.1.1: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 198.18.1.1: TTL expired in transit.

Ping statistics for 198.0.0.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

Comment: So when a switch is acting as router, TTL is supposed to be decremented when crossing a LAN, even it is on same device, right? I know the fact that TTL will be decremented when crossing multiple IP network and not when inside a LAN (L2). It's just that example is really confusing me.

Comment: No. The TTL is decremented as the packet is processed by the network stack. Switches transparently switch frames on the LAN, not looking at the packet. The router module in a layer-3 switch only sees the packet when it strips off the frame as the packet is routed from one network to another network. Think of a layer-3 switch as a separate router and a separate switch put in the same box. A layer-3 switch is first a layer-2 switch. It only routes when a packet is destined for a different network.

Comment: I disagree that the TTL would be decremented when routing to loopback, RFC791 only states that the TTL is decremented when the IP header is processed.  In reality all the major network vendors do not increment TTL when forwarding to a local interface, only if a packet exits a router.

Comment: The IP header is processed when the router determines where to send it next. The destination address is examined in order to determine that the packet is sent out the loopback interface. According to the RFC, the TTL should be decremented. In fact, the TTL is supposed to be decremented by the destination host as the packet is processed by the IP module of the destination host before it is passed to the upper-layer protocols. In reality, none of the host OSes actually do this. The point of the TTL is to protect the upper-layer protocols from old data.

Comment: Using that logic the router would always drop a packet arriving with a TTL of 1 as it would decrement when examining the header on ingress, and drop.  The RFC says when processing, but we can't assume what their definition of processing is as it isn't stated.  As I say, in reality all the major router vendors (Cisco, HPE, Juniper) decrement on physical egress only when rewriting the IP header.  See the example in my response.  I would have to side with their logic as that is how all the equipment I (and most people) work with operates, so that is how TTL processing operates in the real world.

Comment: If you look at the IPv6 RFC, that is exactly what it says a router is supposed to do: `if the IPv6 Hop Limit is less than or equal to 1 {
           send an ICMP Time Exceeded -- Hop Limit Exceeded in
           Transit message to the Source Address and discard the
           packet
        }`

Comment: But we are talking about IPv4, the question is about IPv4.  IPv6 is another protocol.  IPv4 TTL and IPv6 Hop Count are similar, but not the same thing and have protocol definitions.

Comment: TIf you read the IPv6 RFC about the Hop Limit, it explains what the RFC for IPv4 actually means: "_Unlike IPv4, IPv6 nodes are not required to enforce maximum packet lifetime._"

Comment: Still not understanding your logic.  "Unlike IPv4, IPv6 nodes are not required to enforce maximum packet lifetime." only means that IPv4 nodes enforce a hop limit which is something that everyone agrees with and nobody is contradicting (including yourself) and it was no relevance when deciding on whether a router decrements the TTL for loopback / local interfaces.

Comment: I'm explaining what happens. For example, if I ping my Cisco ISR G2 loopback from a directly connected workstation with a TTL of 1, the packet expires before reaching the loopback. The router expires the packet before it reaches the loopback. This conforms to the RFCs.

Comment: And you ping with an IPv4 or IPv6 packet?

Comment: For both IPv4 and IPv6. When the packet reaches the IP module, it is supposed to be decremented before passing it on, even to an upper-layer protocol. I don't know of a PC OS that does this, even though they are supposed to, and that is the reason that the TTL was changed to Hop Limit for IPv6.

Comment: Not sure why you keep talking about PC OSs, we are talking about Cisco (and other vendor) routers and L3 switches which do decrement hop count.  I would not disagree that PC OSs do not decrement TTL.  I would be interested to see some output from your ISR.  All the devices I work on only decrement TTL on egress of a physical interface.

Comment: Its all part of the same thing. The RFC for IPv4 expects the IP module in any layer-3 device, router, PC, etc. to decrement the TTL. Anyway, I need to go right now.

Comment: @KarlBillington, see the edit to my answer. The router decrements the TTL of 1, and it discards the packet, sending an ICMP message that the TTL expired. This is on a Cisco ISR G2.

Comment: Thanks for adding, my device forwards the packet without dropping, I will test on some other equipment and post the results

Comment: It is a moot point, as the OP is asking about IPv4 TTL, and the RFC is obsolete, but your quote from RFC 2460 around "if the IPv6 Hop Limit is less than or equal to 1..."  is part of a nested if statement and it only reaches this branch if routing headers (i.e. source routing) exist, in this case it would make sense to drop as the packet definitely has other router hops to traverse before its destination, so it should be dropped rather than further on in the network.

Answer (score 2):

TTL is checked on ingress packets and decreased when forwarding (=routing) packets. Accordingly, sending out a packet with TTL=1 will enable it to reach a local destination but it will not be routed.

TTL is a layer 3 (IP) scheme, switches don't decrement it (unless they are routing). The *Ethernet frame* has no TTL value whatsoever and the IP TTL isn't changed while switching inside a L2 segment.

Comment: Umm I should say the switches I mentioned are actually routers(L3 switches). Anyway, the problem that confuses me is when packet's destination is on same device but has different IPs on different interfaces. Should TTL be decreased in very same device since it's not forwarding it?

Comment: L3 switches only decrease IP TTL when routing. As long as they're switching (same VLAN) it isn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, IP packets with a TTL of 0 are discarded and the TTL is updated whenever the IP header is processed/rewritten, and usually decremented by 1.  In practice, the TTL is decremented whenever a packet exits a router through a physical interface.

To answer your question more specifically, the TTL is decremented only when it egresses the router.  In your case, for packets destined for the loopback interface or interface 0/2, the packet does not exit the router, the IP header is not updated, so TTL is not decremented and pings are returned.

Looking at a couple of examples using your topology:

- Ping from host 192.168.1.50 to 1.1.1.1 or 192.168.2.1: The ping is
  received by the router on interface 0/1, the TTL is 1 so the packet
  is accepted, the ping is destined for a local interface so the IP
  header is not updated and TTL is not decremented, the packet is
  received by the IP interface (1.1.1.1 or 192.168.2.1).  Ping
  succeeds.
- Ping from host 192.168.1.50 to 192.168.2.50 (a host on the LAN): The
  ping is received by the router on interface 0/1, the TTL is 1 so the
  packet is accepted, a routing decision is made and the packet will be
  routed out of interface 0/2 to the destination (192.168.2.50), at
  this stage the IP header is updated, the TTL is decremented and the
  packet is discarded as the TTL is 0.  Ping fails.

In summary, if you connect your PC to interface 0/1, yes, you should be able to ping interface 0/2 or the loopback interface.  With the same setup, if you attempted to ping another host on 192.168.2.0/24 (not the router), the ping would fail.

I have set this up with Cisco 7200 routers to prove how this works in real life:

- PC1 is connected to router interface E1/1 with IP address 192.168.1.50/24
- PC2 is connected to router interface E1/2 with IP address 192.168.2.50/24
- Router has IP 192.168.1.1/24 on E1/1
- Router has IP 192.168.2.1/24 on E1/2
- Router has loopback address 1.1.1.1/32

First, a ping from PC1 (192.168.1.50) to router E1/2 (192.168.2.1) with TTL of 1 (PING SUCCEEDS):

Router debug output:

```
*Nov  3 20:55:33.447: IP: s=192.168.1.50 (Ethernet1/1), d=192.168.2.1, len 84, rcvd 0
*Nov  3 20:55:33.451:     ICMP type=8, code=0
*Nov  3 20:55:33.451: ICMP: echo reply sent, src 192.168.2.1, dst 192.168.1.50, topology BASE, dscp 0 topoid 0
*Nov  3 20:55:33.451: FIBipv4-packet-proc: route packet from (local) src 192.168.2.1 dst 192.168.1.50
*Nov  3 20:55:33.451: FIBfwd-proc: packet routed by adj to Ethernet1/1 192.168.1.50
*Nov  3 20:55:33.451: FIBipv4-packet-proc: packet routing succeeded
*Nov  3 20:55:33.451: IP: s=192.168.2.1 (local), d=192.168.1.50 (Ethernet1/1), len 84, sending
*Nov  3 20:55:33.451:     ICMP type=0, code=0
R2#
*Nov  3 20:55:33.451: IP: s=192.168.2.1 (local), d=192.168.1.50 (Ethernet1/1), len 84, sending full packet
*Nov  3 20:55:33.455:     ICMP type=0, code=0
*Nov  3 20:55:33.455: IP: s=192.168.1.50 (Ethernet1/1), d=192.168.2.1, len 84, input feature
*Nov  3 20:55:33.455:     ICMP type=8, code=0, packet consumed, MCI Check(88), rtype 0, forus FALSE, sendself FALSE, mtu 0, fwdchk FALSE
```

- Router receives IP packet 192.168.1.50 -> 192.168.2.1
- Router does not route the packet this is a local interface, packet will not exit router
- Router creates an ICMP Echo Reply from 192.168.2.1 -> 192.168.1.50
- Router routes the reply and sends out of interface E1/1

Second, a ping from PC1 (192.168.1.50) to PC2 (192.168.2.50) with TTL of 1 (PING FAILS):

Router debug output:

```
*Nov  3 20:57:23.419: FIBipv4-packet-proc: route packet from Ethernet1/1 src 192.168.1.50 dst 192.168.2.50
*Nov  3 20:57:23.419: FIBfwd-proc: packet routed by adj to Ethernet1/2 192.168.2.50
*Nov  3 20:57:23.419: FIBipv4-packet-proc: packet routing succeeded
*Nov  3 20:57:23.419: ICMP: time exceeded (time to live) sent to 192.168.1.50 (dest was 192.168.2.50), topology BASE, dscp 0 topoid 0
*Nov  3 20:57:23.419: FIBipv4-packet-proc: route packet from (local) src 192.168.1.1 dst 192.168.1.50
*Nov  3 20:57:23.419: FIBfwd-proc: packet routed by adj to Ethernet1/1 192.168.1.50
*Nov  3 20:57:23.419: FIBipv4-packet-proc: packet routing succeeded
R2#
*Nov  3 20:57:23.419: IP: s=192.168.1.1 (local), d=192.168.1.50 (Ethernet1/1), len 56, sending
*Nov  3 20:57:23.419:     ICMP type=11, code=0
*Nov  3 20:57:23.419: IP: s=192.168.1.1 (local), d=192.168.1.50 (Ethernet1/1), len 56, sending full packet
*Nov  3 20:57:23.419:     ICMP type=11, code=0
*Nov  3 20:57:23.419: IP: s=192.168.1.50 (Ethernet1/1), d=192.168.2.50, len 84, input feature
*Nov  3 20:57:23.419:     ICMP type=8, code=0, packet consumed, MCI Check(88), rtype 0, forus FALSE, sendself FALSE, mtu 0, fwdchk FALSE
```

- Router routes the packet from E1/1 to E1/2
- TTL is decremented to 0, time exceeded, packed discarded
- Router sends ICMP TTL exceeded to packet source
- ICMP packet is routed out of E1/1 to PC1

Comment: Does _the IP header is processed_ include a switch that applies an IP ACL on a switched port?

Comment: I guess it could do according to the definition as technically that could be classed as processing, but in practice vendors don’t touch the TTL when it isn’t being L3 forwarded